# Vert.x TemplateHandler (with ThymeleafTemplateEngine) usage problem

Tags: thymeleaf, vert.x

I have problem of using vert.x's TemplateHandler (with Thymeleaf) to render html on server side. I follow the vertx document on 'https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_templates', but still don't know how to solve it.

Following is verticle code :

```
TemplateEngine engine = ThymeleafTemplateEngine.create(vertx);
TemplateHandler handler = TemplateHandler.create(engine);

Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(handler);
router.errorHandler(500, rc -> {
  System.err.println("Handling failure");
  Throwable failure = rc.failure();
  if (failure != null) {
    failure.printStackTrace();
  }
});
```

Following is html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${context.request().params().get('param1')}">hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is exception stack :

```
Handling failure
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "context.request().params().get('param1')" (template: "templates/index.html" - line 8, col 5)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:191)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1067)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.templ.thymeleaf.impl.ThymeleafTemplateEngineImpl.render(ThymeleafTemplateEngineImpl.java:93)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.common.template.TemplateEngine.render(TemplateEngine.java:52)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.TemplateHandlerImpl.handle(TemplateHandlerImpl.java:72)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.handler.impl.TemplateHandlerImpl.handle(TemplateHandlerImpl.java:32)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1104)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:151)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:131)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:55)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:37)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:67)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:30)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:52)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:194)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:140)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:151)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:101)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method request
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1613)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:467)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:431)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.executeExpression(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:316)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(OGNLVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:170)
    ... 66 more
```

Help !!!.

Comment: I have never used Vert.x, but in pure Thymeleaf, you can access [web context](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#web-context-objects) parameters using `${#request.getParameter('param1')}`.

Comment: It's not working, but thanks !

Comment: It does not seem possible to use the routing context object in Thymeleaf by default. There is a solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/issues/2218#issuecomment-1161504867), but it involves using the TemplateEngine directly instead of the TemplateHandler.